Next.js app router error boundary - sending more than just an error message from a server component
All of our fetch work is being done in server components. When a fetch fails, we throw an error in a server component:
// MyServerComponent making the fetch call
try{
   fetch(.....)
}catch(e){
   const myError = new Error("Something went wrong")
   myError.type = "MyCustomType";
   myError.code = 123;
   throw myError;
}



Then the app router has us defining the error boundary (which is a client component) called error.tsx by convention. When the error is thrown from a server component, the error should be passed to this component:
'use client'


interface ErrorProps {
  error: Error & { digest?: string };
}

export default function Error({ error }: ErrorProps) {
  useEffect(() => {
     console.log(error.message) // "Something went wrong"
     console.log(error.type) // undefined
     console.log(error.code) //undefined

  }, [error]);

When I log this I don't see the type or code being passed. I only have access the error.message . Is there a way I can get access to more error properties in my error boundary component besides just the message?

You can write your own Error Boundary

I'm not sure if that actually solves the issue? A custom error boundary would also be a client component that would just receive an error with a message property, but not other properties.
I think the problem is sending the Error from the next server to the client - it strips all properties except the message.

As described here: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/error-handling#handling-server-errors

One option is just send stringified JSON in the message when throwing the error. Then JSON.parse that message in the error boundary component. I don't know if that's a bad pattern though.
